# Chartjs: Cambiar xAxes y yAxes dependiendo el punto que se hizo hover

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Estoy trabajando con Charts.js en la versión [2.9](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/)

Estoy intentando cambiar el color de las etiquetas X y Y del punto al cuál se ha hecho hover, ese punto en algún nodo debería tener almacenados el tick del eje Y y el Eje X en algún lado, para que se cambie de color dichos labels.

Ejemplo, si hago hover en el punto Febrero del dataset "Usuarios mujeres", debería cambiar de color el label del xAxis "Febrero" y del yAxis 30 (por ser el más cercano al valor por método de Math.round() )

He intentado muchas cosas pero la más cercana es la que he punto de ejemplo más abajo. Sólo he conseguido encender todos los xAxis.

¿Qué debería hacer para lograr el cometido?

```js
const data = {
  labels: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril','Mayo', 'Junio'],
  datasets: [
    {
        fill: false,
        label: 'Usuarios hombres',
        data: [67,54,95,41,68, 100],
        backgroundColor: '#4C4CD8',
        borderColor: '#4C4CD8',
        borderWidth : 1,
        pointHoverRadius : 7,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor : '#4C4CD8',
        pointHoverBorderColor : 'rgba(76, 76, 216, 0.1)',
        pointHoverBorderWidth : 10,
    },
    {
        fill: false,
        label: 'Usuarios mujeres',
        data: [21,26,71,43, 36, 10],
        backgroundColor: '#F8CB1C',
        borderColor: '#F8CB1C',
        borderWidth : 1,
        pointHoverRadius : 7,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor : '#F8CB1C',
        pointHoverBorderColor : '#f8cb1c85',
        pointHoverBorderWidth : 10
    }
  ]
};

const options = {
  onHover : (event, activeElements) => {
  if (activeElements.length > 0) {
    const chart = activeElements[0]._chart;
    const element = activeElements[0];
    // change the color of Xaxis on  hover event
    chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontColor = ['orange'];
    chart.update();
    }
  }
};

new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

A buenas no se puede, hay un [bug](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442) que impide modificar cada ticks por separado.

Habría que intentar por la malas, ya que en javascript es posible pisar funciones:

1.- Crear una función que reemplace [_drawLabels](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/171a7e3a7a23b1d4a9d37ed2b2495698969b79d5/src/core/core.scale.js#L1300)

2.- Asignar esta función a los ejes X e Y

3.- Utilizar algún evento del tooltip para rescatar los puntos

4.- Guardar estos puntos en una variable, para llamarlos en la función creada en (1)

Ejemplo

```js
const data = {
  labels: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril','Mayo', 'Junio'],
  datasets: [
    {
        fill: false,
        label: 'Usuarios hombres',
        data: [67,54,95,41,68, 100],
        backgroundColor: '#4C4CD8',
        borderColor: '#4C4CD8',
        borderWidth : 1,
        pointHoverRadius : 7,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor : '#4C4CD8',
        pointHoverBorderColor : 'rgba(76, 76, 216, 0.1)',
        pointHoverBorderWidth : 10,
    },
    {
        fill: false,
        label: 'Usuarios mujeres',
        data: [21,26,71,43, 36, 10],
        backgroundColor: '#F8CB1C',
        borderColor: '#F8CB1C',
        borderWidth : 1,
        pointHoverRadius : 7,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor : '#F8CB1C',
        pointHoverBorderColor : '#f8cb1c85',
        pointHoverBorderWidth : 10
    }
  ]
};


     
const options = {
  tooltips: {
      intersect: false,
       mode: 'point',
       custom: function (tooltip) {
          //cuando muestra el tooltip
          if( tooltip.opacity > 0 ) {
              let tooltipItem = tooltip.dataPoints[0];
              //guardamos el label que hay cambiar de color del eje X
              chart.scales['x-axis-0'].Marca = {
                  color: "Red",
                  label: tooltipItem.label
              };

              let yvalue = Number(tooltipItem.value);
              //buscamos el label mas cercano del eje Y
              let num = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].ticks.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(curr - yvalue) < Math.abs(prev - yvalue) ? curr : prev);

              //guardamos el label que hay cambiar de color del eje Y
              chart.scales['y-axis-0'].Marca = {
                  color: "Red",
                  label: String(num)
              };
          }
          else //cuando oculta el tooltip
          {
              chart.scales['x-axis-0'].Marca = null;
              chart.scales['y-axis-0'].Marca = null;
          }
          return;

      }

   }
};

//creamos una función pintar Ticks, que es una copia de la original, con ligerios cambios
const Pintar = function () {        
   var me = this;
   var optionTicks = me.options.ticks;

   if (!optionTicks.display) {
       return;
   }

   var ctx = me.ctx;
   var items = me._labelItems || (me._labelItems = me._computeLabelItems());
   var i, j, ilen, jlen, item, tickFont, label, y;

   for (i = 0, ilen = items.length; i < ilen; ++i) {
       item = items[i];
       tickFont = item.font;

       // Make sure we draw text in the correct color and font
       ctx.save();
       ctx.translate(item.x, item.y);
       ctx.rotate(item.rotation);
       ctx.font = tickFont.string;
        label = item.label;
        
        //Comprobamos si el label es uno de los que hay que pintar, y si es así establecemos su color
       ctx.fillStyle = (me.Marca && me.Marca.label == label) ? me.Marca.color : tickFont.color;
       ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
       ctx.textAlign = item.textAlign;

       y = item.textOffset;
       if (label instanceof Array) {
           for (j = 0, jlen = label.length; j < jlen; ++j) {
               // We just make sure the multiline element is a string here..
               ctx.fillText('' + label[j], 0, y);
               y += tickFont.lineHeight;
           }
       } else {
           ctx.fillText(label, 0, y);
       }
       ctx.restore();
   }
};

//inicializamos el gráfico

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
 let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data,
     options
 });
 
 //sobreescribimos las funciones de pintar ticks
 
chart.scales['x-axis-0']._drawLabels = Pintar;
chart.scales['y-axis-0']._drawLabels = Pintar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```